# How do I interpret this 404 finding?

Tags: http-status-code-404, analytics

In Google Analytics, this page was shown as a landing page and eventually a visited page:

**subdomain.domain.com.au/404.html?page=/&from=**

The tracking code in place goes like this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview', '404.html?page='+ document.location.pathname + document.location.search +'&from=' + document.referrer);
</script>
```

If I am to interpret the URL shown by Analytics, the visit that resulted to a 404 is a visit to "/", right? If I am right, how come "/" results to a 404?

Then here's another URL shown that's 404-related:

**subdomain.domain.com.au/404.html?page=/sample-page/&from=http://subdomain.domain.com.au/**

Does this mean that the visit that resulted into a 404 was made to "/sample-page/" and that it originated from "subdomain.domain.com.au/"?

But then "/sample-page/" is actually up so why would it show a 404? Plus, there are no any wrong links present at "subdomain.domain.com.au/" so how could a wrong page originate from it?

This is really confusing me. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know for certain that the 404 virtual page view code is applied to only 404 pages? And your interpretations of those URLs is accurate.

Comment: @nyuen Thanks for that. You're right, the above tracking code is actually what's present on "all" pages. I didn't realize that it should be placed "only" on the 404 page. But since we're using Wordpress and the tracking code is placed on the header file (which applies to "all" pages), how do I make it appear only on the 404 page and have a separate tracking code for the rest of the pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow one of these Wordpress links to create a 404 template where you can also apply the GA 404 code:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-improve-your-404-page-template-in-wordpress/

Or simply search for Wordpress 404 plugins.

I am not totally familiar with WP so you may need to see how much of the GA code needs to be included. And don't forget to fix the existing pageview code by removing the 404 bit.

Comment: Thanks! We already have a 404 page in place. I'm still tracking its origin and will start from there (currently unable to find it on the themes folders but hopefully will find it soon). The pageview code on the header file has also already been replaced which, sadly, also took effect on the 404 page.